# How Google Pay figure out user's payment methods?

Tags: google-pay

Does Google Pay use Google Account's session cookies to figure out which payment method user can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Pay payment methods are attached to a Google profile and available when logged in.

On the web, if the user is NOT logged into a Google account when initiating a Google Pay payment, the user will be prompted to log in.

Cookies are involved in maintaining authenticated user state.

Comment: can you ansswer my questions for google pay : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327500/where-is-google-pay-developer-account-and-how-to-generate-public-key-to-upload-i